# Assign Pacific Standard Time Zone in R (with no daylight saving)

Tags: r, time, timezone, lubridate, posixct

I am working on an hourly time series dataset—the location of the data in California, while the column showing the date and time with POSIXct is in UTC. I want my time label to show local time at regular intervals, so I want to avoid daylight saving time.

If the dataset is in New York, my plan to handle the dataset is as follows:

```
# Load packages
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

# Create example data frame
# The time zone is in UTC
dat <- data.frame(
  Time = as.POSIXct(c("2022-03-13 06:00:00",
                      "2022-03-13 07:00:00",
                      "2022-03-13 08:00:00",
                      "2022-03-13 09:00:00",
                      "2022-03-13 10:00:00",
                      "2022-03-13 11:00:00"), tz = "UTC")
)

# Convert to Eastern Standard Time Zone
# This is my preferred output
dat2 <- dat %>%
  mutate(Time = with_tz(Time, tz = "America/Jamaica"))

print(dat2$Time)
# [1] "2022-03-13 01:00:00 EST" "2022-03-13 02:00:00 EST" "2022-03-13 03:00:00 EST" "2022-03-13 04:00:00 EST" "2022-03-13 05:00:00 EST"
# [6] "2022-03-13 06:00:00 EST"

# Convert to Eastern daylight saving time
# This is not my preferred output, but an example
dat3 <- dat %>%
  mutate(Time = with_tz(Time, tz = "America/New_York"))

dat3$Time
# [1] "2022-03-13 01:00:00 EST" "2022-03-13 03:00:00 EDT" "2022-03-13 04:00:00 EDT" "2022-03-13 05:00:00 EDT" "2022-03-13 06:00:00 EDT"
# [6] "2022-03-13 07:00:00 EDT"
```

Notice that `dat2` is my preferred output. It is not the correct time in New York as daylight saving time begins at 2022-03-13. However, I want the interval between each time point is the same.

Now my question is: how to do the same for a California dataset? I could only find cities in Pacific time zone with daylight saving time. In other words, I don't know how to specify a time zone name using `with_tz` to make the `Time` column showing "PST" with regular intervals during daylight saving transition. Using "America/Los_Angeles" will not work.

Comment: Does the "Etc/GMT+8" timezone work for you?

Comment: I guess I don't understand (or agree with) the premise of the problem. Yes, I see that the four lines have a gap in the hour number, but `diff(dat3$Time)` returns `Time differences in hours \n [1] 1 1 1 1 1` (all gaps are one hour). Don't confuse `diff(hour(dat3$Time))` with `diff(dat3$Time)`, they are very different things.

Comment: You'll have the added problem that if you get it to avoid the _perceived_ gap in time, it'll be wrong (off by an hour) for half the year.

Comment: But you can come closer using `"US/Arizona"`: it's one hour off (half the year) and does not practice DST.

Comment: @r2evans Thanks. I understand internally the time difference in hour is still 1. I just want the time to be displayed with local time and regular interval. I am studying a natural phenomenon. The day-light saving time is a human invention irrelevant to the natural cycle and my research topic.